# What is the sumproduct syntax in vba?

Tags: vba, vba6

What is the correct syntax for sum product?

Here is my code:

```
mFormula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--((1.Insert_Data!F:F)=2.Counting_sheet!A8)),(--((1.Insert_Data!E:E)))"
Range("C8") = Evaluate(mFormula)
```

Comment: What makes you think that's incorrect?  In other words, what happens when you run that?

Comment: Why don't you use `Range("C8").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--((1.Insert_Data!F:F)=2.Counting_sheet!A8)),(--((1.Insert_Data!E:E)))"`? It should work

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are not balanced

```vb
mFormula = "=SUMPRODUCT(  --(('1.Insert_Data'!F:F)='2.Counting_Sheet'!A8), " & _
                         "--('1.Insert_Data'!E:E)  )"

Range("C8") = Evaluate(mFormula)
```

Comment: If you use the same formula in a worksheet cell does it work?  Is the workbook containing those sheets active?

Comment: Dim e As Integer
Dim v As Integer
Dim mFormula As String

For e = 8 To 120
    mFormula = "=SUMPRODUCT(  --(('1.Insert_Data'!F:F) = '2.Counting_sheet'!A&e), " & _
                         "'1.Insert_Data'!E:E)"
    Range("C" & e) = Evaluate(mFormula)
Next e



Still did not work instead gave me a name error

Answer (score 0):

```
mFormula = "=SUMPRODUCT(  --(('1.Insert_Data'!F:F) = '2.Counting_sheet'!A8), " & _
                     "'1.Insert_Data'!E:E)"
```

this is the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

Sub itemno()
'

'
Dim e As Integer
Dim mFormula As String

For e = 8 To 120

```
mFormula = "=SUMPRODUCT(  --(('1.Insert_Data'!F:F) = '2.Counting_sheet'!A" & e & ")," & _
                     "'1.Insert_Data'!E:E)"
                     
                     
Range("C" & e).Value = mFormula
```

Next e

End Sub